# I pick a date from DatePicker and then want to start another activity

Tags: android, datepicker

when i pick the date from DatePicker then i want to start another
    activity(GetAttendance) ,but it takes me two times there,which i want for one time.Is  it possible to call for one time?

//code

```
   classes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try
            { 
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

             } catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }               
         }
    });
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch (id) {
     case DATE_DIALOG_ID:      // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, obj,year, month,day);
    }
    return null;        
};
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener obj=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{       
     @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int    dayOfMonth)
     {
        try 
         {  dday=dayOfMonth;
            mmonth=monthOfYear;
            yyear=year;
             getDateString=parseDateMethod(dday,mmonth,yyear);
        } catch (Exception e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            pd=ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "passing List", "Processing");
            new   AttendanceAthnticate().execute();             
        }       
        //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Date is  "+getDateString,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

//AsynTask:

```
private class AttendanceAthnticate extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  ArrayList<SetAttendance>>
{
  ArrayList<SetAttendance> listAtt;
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SetAttendance> doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        listAtt=new AllMethods().getAttendance();
        pd.cancel();
        return listAtt; 
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SetAttendance> result) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(result.size()>0)
            {


  Intent iii=new Intent(Home.this,GetAttendance.class);//It takes me two time which    i    want for one time
                iii.putExtra("shahid", result);
                startActivity(iii);
            }
            else
            {

            }

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: it must be crash application.

Comment: what should i do to avoid from crash application

Comment: comment this line pd.cancel();

Comment: I comment it but progressDialog is on processing and also takes two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34860), it seems like `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()` is called two times when a date is set. So it's normal that you have this bug.

A possible solution is this one:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener obj=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{  

     boolean alreadyFired = false;      

     @Override 
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int    dayOfMonth) 
     {
           if (alreadyFired == false)
           {
              try  
               {  dday=dayOfMonth; 
                  mmonth=monthOfYear; 
                  yyear=year; 
                  getDateString=parseDateMethod(dday,mmonth,yyear); 
               } catch (Exception e)  
               { 
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
               } 
               finally 
               { 
                pd=ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "passing List", "Processing"); 
                new   AttendanceAthnticate().execute();              
               }        
               //Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Date is  "+getDateString,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               alreadyFired = true;
           }
           else
           {
               alreadyFired = false;
           }
    } 
};
```

Comment: it still  takes me two times.

Comment: @ShahidBangash Check my edit and tell me if it changes something.